# How to get google ads sdk to work in Intellij?

Tags: android, crash, intellij-idea, android-manifest, adsense

Silly question (noob here) but the tag below in `AndroidManifest.xml` doesnt work in IntelliJ. The app compiles successfully but crashes on launch.  This manifest file works fine in Eclipse. I added the `googleadmob*.jar` file in the sdk part of the project structure settings.

```
<activity
android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" 
...

</activity>
```

Comment: What error do you get on crash?

Comment: Please provide the stacktrace.

Comment: what do you mean by "doesnt work" ? Is it just that the class name is red font?

Comment: Added to the SDK? Are you sure that you don't need to add it as a module library instead so that it's packaged with your application? Otherwise it may not work as these classes will be missing on the device.

Comment: @CrackerJack9 yes, just the AdaActivity is in red.

Comment: @Niek ill provide stack trace later (had to learn first how to do that).

Comment: @CrazyCoder i dont understand "add as module library" as it is a jar file already? forgive my noobness on these things. I added it in dependencies but to no avail as well.

Comment: See http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html.

Comment: @crazycoder Thanks very much, now it works ok. The weird thing is Intellij still highlights the AdActivity in red font and if i hover the mouse over, it says cannot resolve symbol.

Comment: Try File | Invalidate Caches. I've also added an answer that you can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've added the jar to the SDK. It must be configured as a module library instead, [refer to the documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html). In this case it will be packaged with your application, while SDK is not packaged as it's already available on the device.

If the class is still shown in red in the editor, try `File` | `Invalidate Caches`.

Comment: Thank you, that sorted it out.